# AnimatableData for Line Chart in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

I'd like to create animation of the line chart like drawing from start point to end point.
I've created `InsettableShape` (code below) in order to use with `strokeBorder()`, but can't figure out how to define `animatableData`.

Thank you!

(I know I can do it with `Shape` and `trim()`, but I need `inset`.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct LineChartInsettableShape: InsettableShape {
    let series: [CGFloat]

    var insetAmount: CGFloat = 0

    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var chart = self
        chart.insetAmount += amount
        return chart
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        guard !series.isEmpty else { return Path() }

        let minY = series.min()!
        let maxY = series.max()!

        let xStep = (rect.width - insetAmount * 2) / CGFloat(series.count - 1)

        func point(index: Int) -> CGPoint {
            let yValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(series[index])

            return CGPoint(
                x: xStep * CGFloat(index) + insetAmount,
                y: (rect.height - insetAmount * 2) * (1 - (yValue - minY) / (maxY - minY)) + insetAmount
            )
        }

        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: point(index: 0))

            for index in 1..<series.count {
                path.addLine(to: point(index: index))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to do this this shape and which parameters to animate. Would you elaborate more on this? Probably with some demo?

Comment: There is a bar chart library, you can check it out as well https://github.com/dawigr/BarChart

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard once you figure it out, but initially how this works can be a bit confusing. You need to have a property named `animatableData` which tells SwiftUI the name of the variable you'll be using for animation, and how to get it and set its value. For example, I have a small piece of animation code that uses a variable named `inset`, which is very similar to your `insetAmount`. Here's all the code my app needs to use this variable for animation:

```
var inset: CGFloat

var animatableData: CGFloat {
    get { inset }
    set { self.inset = newValue}
}
```

Not all data types can be used for animation. `CGFloat`, used here, certainly can be. Paul Hudson has an excellent short video on this topic: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/animating-simple-shapes-with-animatabledata.